# checking a value for reset value before resetting it - performance impact?

Tags: java, performance, variables

I have a variable that gets read and updated thousands of times a second. It needs to be reset regularly.  But "half" the time, the value is already the reset value. Is it a good idea to check the value first (to see if it needs resetting) before resetting (a write operaion), or I should just reset it regardless? The main goal is to optimize the code for performance.

To illustrate:

```
Random r = new Random();
int val = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

for (int i=0; i<100000000; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0)
        val = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    else
        val = r.nextInt();

    if (val != Integer.MAX_VALUE) //skip check?
        val = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

I tried to use the above program to test the 2 scenarios (by un/commenting the 2nd "if" line), but any difference is masked by the natural variance of the run duration time.

Thanks.

Comment: So you want to reset the value everytime it is updated in the else block after you are done with the changed value?

Comment: Even though my test program shows no difference, I am thinking in a more complex program, what I choose to do may have a performance impact.

Comment: I would not do that check. check yourself using System.currentTimeNanos() to measure.

Comment: The code I included is for demonstration only.  My real program does a lot more between the time I set the value, and coming back later to reset it.

Comment: @FaiNg, Your example code doesn't make much sense.

Comment: This test program may not work as intended because the Java compiler would optimize this code in such a way that the check may not be there anymore.

Comment: You should not be using `Integer.MAX_VALUE` as "not set". A better approach would be use use an `Integer` and use `null` as "not set".

Comment: The int val is actually a marker for a stream of char's i am handling. Together with another marker, I have a length in between. Thus val = 0 is a valid value, and val = small neg value will give me an invalid length, but not noticeably so. With val set to max int, my length will always be negative telling me the length is invalid.  I will think about using Integer (but using Integer vs int will not be much slower? I will do more testing). Just that my code is for parsing millions and millions of char's, thus want it to be as efficient as possible

Comment: First time posting questions in Stackover.  Very useful answers and comments in many ways. Let me know if I am not doing something right etiquette-wise.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't check it.

It's more execution steps = more cycles = more time.

As an aside, you are breaking one of the basic software golden rules: "Don't optimise early". Unless you have hard evidence that this piece if code is a performance problem, you shouldn't be looking at it. (Note that doesn't mean you code without performance in mind, you still follow normal best practice, but you don't add any special code whose only purpose is "performance related")

Answer (score 0):

The check has no actual performance impact. We'd be talking about a single clock cycle or something, which is usually not relevant in a Java program (as hard-core number crunching usually isn't done in Java).

Instead, base the decision on readability. Think of the maintainer who's going to change this piece of code five years on.

In the case of your example, using my rationale, I would skip the check.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the JIT will optimise the code away because it doesn't do anything.

Rather than worrying about performance, it is usually better to worry about what it

- simpler to understand
- cleaner to implement

In both cases, you might remove the code as it doesn't do anything useful and it could make the code faster as well.

Even if it did make the code a little slower it would be very small compared to the cost of calling `r.nextInt()` which is not cheap.